# Passing parameter for link-to in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js

for some reason i need to pass my route one extra parameter with linkTo and use this parameter in my Route i try to find a way and find some [source](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_link-to) but its not enough my suggestion is like this :

```
 {{#link-to 'someRoute' parameter1}}

 {{#link-to 'someRoute' parameter2}}

 App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   //using parameter
 });
```

is it possible to use `transitionTo` and pass parameter when changing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multiple parameters with the link to helper.

```
 {{#link-to 'someNestedRoute' model1 model2}}Deep Route{{/link-to}}
```

You also can use transitionTo from a route (or transitionToRoute from controller) and send in multiple models as well.

```
  transitionTo('someNestedRoute', model1, model2);
```